# How to find form widgets under a given fieldset?

Tags: forms, dojo

I have a `dojox/form/Manager` form with several levels of nesting, similar to this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8YDjT/1/

Given the name of one of the `Fieldset`s, how can I find all of the **form widgets** underneath it?

E.g. given `fields_b`, how can I find the widgets `b_1`, `b_2`, and `b_3`, without hardcoding their names or other such shenanigans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `getDescendants()` you can get all children (on all levels) from a specific widget. You can then verify the class of the widget with `myWidget.declaredClass` to check if the widget is a `dijit.form.*` or not.

For example:

```js
require(["dijit/registry", "dojo/ready", "dojo/parser", "dojox/form/Manager", "dijit/Fieldset", "dijit/form/TextBox"], function (registry, ready) {
    ready(function() {
        registry.byId("fieldset_a").getDescendants().forEach(function(widget) {
            if (widget.declaredClass.match(/^dijit\.form\./i)) {
                 console.log(widget); // Form widget
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I also forked your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/tnJGB/1/). But I removed the `dojo/domReady!` and switched over to automatic parsing with `data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true"` and to the `dojo/ready` module since the callback will only be executed when the DOM is ready **AND** the dojo widgets (dijit) are parsed.

Comment: That's great, thanks! I was thinking of using dojo/query but that doesn't specifically look for widgets so it would probably get tricky.

Comment: `dojo/query` is meant for DOM nodes. Dojo splits widgets and DOM nodes and to retrieve a widget you should be using `dijit/registry`.